# Problem with shared ssh keys

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, centos, authentication

Following the process I've used in [other environments](http://www.trilug.org/pipermail/trilug/Week-of-Mon-20080602/054712.html), I've tried setting-up shared keys between my Mac and my CentOS 4 webserver. I've seen the same problem with my older Ubuntu 7.10 workstation trying to connect via keys to the same webserver.

I have tried both `dsa` and `rsa` keytypes (`sshkeygen -t <type>`).

The `sshd_config` file on my webserver seems to be allowing key-based logins:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And my .ssh/authorized_keys has my `dsa` and `rsa` keys added.

Where should I be looking for what to change next to make key-based logins "Just Work™"?

Is it related to the line,

```
#UseDNS yes
```

and `sshd` is trying to do a reverse-lookup on my IP, but cannot because it's NAT'd?

Comment: `ssh -v` to get verbose diagnostics could help pin down the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/.ssh/` permissions should be set `0700`, and the contents should be `0600`.

Also, permissions on `~/` must be 0755 or less; that is, it cannot be writable by any other users.

Comment: Aha! Similar to permissions requirements for .forward files. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This [Ubuntu page on SSH Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) is good reading (look at [`Troubleshooting`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting)).

Answer (score 1):

add some -v option when you initiate your ssh connection as

```
ssh <user>@<host> -vvv
```

If ever you have the admin rights to the server, you could also **strace -f -p  SSHD_PID** your sshd

Both of them will give you a bunch of info....

Answer (score 0):

CentOS or Ret Hat maintain old versions of packages, so I think this is an issue with, say OpenSSH 5 connecting to older versions.

If I recall, you probably need to have a file called `authorized_keys2` instead of just `authorized_keys` on the server end.