# ssh passwordless -login

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH asks for password, even with public key installed](https://superuser.com/questions/201138/ssh-asks-for-password-even-with-public-key-installed)

http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html

I am trying to login from machine A to machine B with password-less SSH login as described in the above link.I have followed all the steps but still the password is being prompted for.How to diagnose this and resolve the issue

Comment: Better to ask this on serverfault.com?

Comment: @knitatoms, please don't invite people to repost their question on another site. Things will be moved automatically if people vote for that. No need to *ask* for duplicates! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit: /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or equivalent for your distribution)

And make sure the following lines are set as shown:

```
....
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
...
```

Be careful though - you could lock yourself out.  Here's a good guide:

http://www.debuntu.org/ssh-key-based-authentication

Comment: @Knitamatoms:On which machine this should be done

Comment: Machine B if that is the one you are connecting to.

Comment: @Knitamatoms:I believe thats not the problem ,bcoz i have configured another machine with the options mentioned as yes

Answer (score 1):

You can still keep password-based authentication (PasswordAuthentication Yes) and use keys when you have them. I have a box here for shared git that we all use our own ssh keys (using .ssh/authorized_keys) but my user account I login with a username/password. The key is adding the public side of the key to .ssh/authorized_keys file on the server you want to login to remotely.