# Why does SSH with .pem file ask for password?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

I'm trying to SSH from a Mac into an EC2 instance with the following command:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@54.164.172.194
```

When I enter this, a dialog is displayed that prompts me to enter a password. `key.pem` contains my private RSA key, which I don't have a password for. Am I missing something?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/201138/ssh-asks-for-password-even-with-public-key-installed?rq=1

Comment: Is the public key for your private key setup as an authorized key?